When is Power function strongly convex?

A function $f : \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is strongly convex, if
$\exists r >0$ s.t $f(x)-r ||x||^2$ is convex.
Let $f: [0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}, f(x)=x^\alpha, \alpha >0$. Find all the
value of $\alpha$ s.t $f$ is strongly convex on $[0,\infty)$.

My attempt:
I need to find $\alpha >0$ s.t there exists $r>0$ s.t $g(x)=x^\alpha - r||x||^2=x^\alpha - rx^2$ is convex on $[0,\infty)$.
If $\alpha =2,g(x)=x^2(1-r)$. We can choose $r=\dfrac{1}{2}$ and $g(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}x^2$ is convex on $[0,\infty)$.
I'm stuck at the case $\alpha\neq 2$.
I already proved for $\alpha \geq 1,x^\alpha$ is convex on $[0,\infty)$.
Could someone help me to with this case? Thanks in advance!

A smoth function is convex if $f''(x)>0$. Use this for $\alpha >2$. For $1\le \alpha<2$ see if $f'$ is increasing.

@geetha290krm if $\alpha >2$, the condition $f''(x)>0$ is equivalent with $\dfrac{\alpha (\alpha  -1)x^{\alpha  -2}}{2}\geq r\quad\forall x\in [0,\infty)$. As $x\to 0, r\to 0$. Does there exist $r$ s.t $g(x)$ is convex on $[0,\infty)$?

@geetha290krm If $1\leq\alpha <2, g'(x)=x^{\alpha -1}(\alpha-2x^{2-\alpha}r)$. Could you show me how can I know whether this $g'(x)$ is increasing or not? Also, do you have any way to deal with the case $\alpha<1$?

If $x^{\alpha}-rx^{2}$ is convex then $x^{\alpha}=(x^{\alpha}-rx^{2})+rx^{2}$ would be convex (as the sum of two convex functions). This is not true if $0<\alpha <1$.

@geetha290krm could you help me with 2 remaining cases?

The problem is harder than it looks. If anyone could write down the complete solution to the problem in the answering section down below, I would be very much appreciated
